# Weapon for a Horse

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mounted-combat

I play a Cavalier, and I am always on horse back.

When I fight, my horse's bite attack does a significant amount of damages. Sometimes more than myself.

But I just can't picture a Horse fighting with it's jaws, like a panther or a dog.

Is there a way for me do give my horse a weapon ?

Like a spike on his head or something like that and give him the appropriate feat to use it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical Large [horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse) could employ designed-for-a-Large-creature [**armor spikes**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/armor-spikes)/[spiked armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spiked-armor) (+100 gp, +20 lbs.) and, whether [proficient with this martial weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/martial-weapon-proficiency---final) or not, use its base attack bonus to make attacks with the weapon, and gain iterative attacks with the weapon on a full attack were its base attack bonus sufficient in addition to using its natural weapons. The horse *will* suffer a −4 penalty on attack rolls with the weapon if it lacks proficiency, however. Plus, armor spikes/spiked armor can be made magical.

Such a weapon lets the horse stab opponents instead of (*and*, when it's feeling ornery, *in addition to*) snapping at opponents with its mighty jaw.

Answer (score 9):

**Ask your DM if you can reflavor the bite as a kick.**

If you have trouble envisioning your horse biting foes (though horses can actually bite quite hard, and will do so if provoked) ask your DM if the attack can be reflavored as a kick with front or rear legs as appropriate. Horses can kick hard enough to break skulls; the bite stats are, if anything, weaker than what actually being kicked by a horse would do.

Answer (score 5):

Pathfinder isn't a system I have explored in depth, but I do train horses, so I can cast some light from that side of things. Horses have very strong, powerful jaws and even a relatively mild bite hurts *a lot*. A severe bite can certainly take a chunk out of you or sever fingers and a horse that habitually bites people is dangerous to be around.

If you really want to use something else that makes sense in terms of how a horse fights, they will kick out with their back feet ( with bone-breaking power ) if something they are concerned about is behind them, but a trained warhorse would be more likely to strike out with a front hoof. This is an unbelievably fast forward kick with the front legs, which you would usually only see in nature from an aggressive stallion. They don't rear up, they simply lash out. If someone is knocked down ( and a horse can knock down most people just by running into them ) an aggressive horse might paw at them on the ground. The capacity for aggression is closer to the surface on stallions, which is one reason they tended to be used as warhorses historically.

These are natural behaviours, but by nature a horse is way more flight than fight, so if you are concerned about realism you would need a well-trained warhorse to use them in battle. The average riding horse would be more likely to be intimidated by that kind of situation and be inclined to try and get itself ( and possibly you ) to somewhere safer, as quickly as possible.